# connection to cluster failed when running apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --baseline

Tags: docker, ignite

I am using ignite as docker containers and cant seem to run `apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --baseline` when I setup the container to connect to the host network. When I specify a virtual network name and ip address I am able to run the command.
The error I receive is

```
Connection to cluster failed.
Error: Latest topology update failed.
```

These are the commands I used when creating my containers
IP Address mode

```
sudo docker run --name ignite -m 32G -d --net=nic4 --ip=192.168.102.154 -e "CONFIG_URI=http://192.168.102.119/api/hostmonitor/generateigniteconfigxml/true/192-168-102-154/datacenter2" -e "JVM_OPTS=-Xms12g -Xmx12g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC" apacheignite/ignite:2.7.6
```

HOST mode

```
sudo docker run --name ignite -m 32G -d --net=host -e "CONFIG_URI=http://192.168.102.119/api/hostmonitor/generateigniteconfigxml/true/192-168-102-154/datacenter2" -e "JVM_OPTS=-Xms12g -Xmx12g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC" apacheignite/ignite:2.7.6
```

any ideas if something is being blocked or not allowing it to be ran in host mode network?

Comment: I think this is probably a false positive warning. You can configure Critical Failures Handler to make these messages go away: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling

Comment: But I am still not able to query the baseline from that node. What benefit is there if i do end up hiding these messages? As I am not able to access the cluster and/or add remove nodes from it

Comment: Could you clarify once again what doesn’t work out on your end and who reports the error - one of the sever nodes or the script? It might be the case that the script and server cannot reach out each other if the script is executed outside of Docker environment

Comment: To clarify I just cannot run the command apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --baseline on the docker container when I create it with host as the network. I wanted to be able to view the cluster information, see the nodes in the cluster...etc. But cannot do so. If I do end up creating a container via IP address and specific network I am able to run the command and get the cluster information. I can however see the node that is created via host from the other node created via IP address and specific network